# SyntaxNode from Microsoft.CodeAnalysis (Roslyn) shows IncompleteMember, although the class is fine

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, code-analysis

I have to scan over many C# files, to extract some data. The process itself is done and worked so far.
But now it started to not work anymore. No idea why.
At first, I couldn't build a SyntaxTree. When going document.GetsyntaxTreeAsync(), it would produce an empty syntaxtree.

When I worked around that (by going `var root = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(File.ReadAllText(document.FileName)).GetRoot();`), another problem emerged I can't seem to find a solution for.

I'm getting the current class name by starting from an inner node (please don't ask why - I didn't write it), going

```
node.Ancestors().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First.Identifier.ToString();
```

And now, there is no ClassDeclarationSyntax, because most of the ancestor nodes are `IncompleteMember`s. In a perfectly fine class. It compiles, runs, etc.

Just the CodeAnalysis library wont find it.

When I go `node.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().ToFullString()` it actually has the whole file, without errors.

Comment: sounds like you have an issue with your workspace? You should look into getting document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync work again

Comment: That's what I'd like to do. But I can't, as I don't know what's wrong, and I don't know where to start. I thought it just reads the file into a string, and then parses it. Not much that could go wrong, except not being able to open the file.

Comment: Can you post the document you're parsing?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I can tell you anything you want about it (as far as I remember, I'm actually on vacation now). I know it compiles and runs just fine.